Call function on js obj with Jint
I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like this in Jint: calling a function on an object instance like this:
.js
class TestObject {
    ...
    test() {
        console.log("Hello, this is a test");
    }
}

.cs
...
var engine = new Engine()
var objInstance = engine
    .Evaluate("new TestObject()")
    .ToObject() as dynamic;

engine.Invoke(objInstance.test);
...

Thanks a lot everybody!
I tried the above and a ton of other variations, but I always get:

'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'test'

